# Which approach is faster ? Accessing locators from java class or external file (JSON) in Page Factory

Tags: automation

Framework ingredients - Cucumber & Selenium (Java), Page Object Model & Page Factory.

Currently I am writing locators in below way -

Class -> HomePage.java

```
@FindAll({  
        @FindBy(css = HomePageLocators.factoryBouncePopUp),
        @FindBy(xpath = HomePageLocators.outletBouncePopUp),
    }) public List<WebElement> bouncePopUp;
```

Class -> HomePageLocators.java

```
    public final static String factoryBouncePopUp = "div[id*=bx-creative] > div > a";
    public final static String outletBouncePopUp = "//button[contains(.,'NO THANKS, I PREFER TO PAY FULL PRICE')]";
```

As we know we can pass locators as constants in @FindBy annotations. So i started to write down locators in java class. Things are working smoothly.

But i have been thinking to write down locators in an external file say json thinking it would be easier to maintain locators in json specially when locators are going to be huge in count lets say 600. I came across below link to know how to access locators from json in page factory.

https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/pagefactory-page-objects-and-locators-from-an-external-file/

I want to know opinion of this community, from performance point of view, which approach would be advisable. I shall not think about json with page factory in case performance is going to be an issue.

If Json could win in performance race then anyone can suggest me any source of implementing json in page factory apart from the above link.

Any thought would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to access the locator values in that case Interface in java is the best option .You do not need to interact with any other file type.In interface you can get data directly and it will be also static and final you just can call it Interface name.LocatorName. It will not impact your performance.